# Magnolia CMS: property inheritance

Tags: magnolia

Using Magnolia CMS, I am trying to make a property inherit through all child pages.
The property gets set from a base page dialog.

Essentially its just a checkbox that toggles a show/hide Boolean that gets tested in the main page template (which child pages also use).

The dialog control component 'hideHeader' has this structure:

```
::hideHeader
  .buttonLabel: Hide
  .class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.CheckboxFieldDefinition;
  .defaultValue: true;
  .i18n: true;
  .inheritable: true;
  .label: hide;
  .type: Boolean;
```

Which is added to the base page dialog.

I access the property in the template like:

```
[#assign hideHeader = false /]

[#if content.hideHeader?? && content.hideHeader?has_content ]
  [#assign hideHeader = content.hideHeader /]
[/#if]
```

I cant get it to work in the child pages. It doesn't pick up on the set value from the dialog, just the default 'false' value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

In order to inherit property from anywhere up in the hierarchy of pages, you need to use `cmsfn.inheritProperty(content, "your-prop-name")`.

Using only `stkfn.siteRoot(content)` as suggested above, will return you root node of the site, so if value was overridden anywhere in the hierarchy you would not see that.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: The link you provided gives 404 :(

Answer (score 1):

so after suffering from 'code' blindness, I realised to implement the behaviour I wanted I needed to get the property using:

```
stkfn.siteRoot(content)
```

this now enables all sub pages to receive the parent pages properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of all code above you can just use:

`[#assign hideHeader = content.hideHeader!false]`

2. To inherit property you have function in TemplatingFunctions

`public Property inheritProperty(Node content, String relPath)`

in freemarker you should do something like:

```
cmsfn.inheritProperty(content, "hideHeader ");
```